# How to export Alembic Mesh Sequence Cache to FBX?

Tags: export, .fbx, alembic

I am making demolition animation for a realtime render engine that does not support Alembic, so I am trying to convert Alembic import from Blender to FBX, but only the first frame of the animation gets exported to FBX, so I was wondering if there was a way to convert the Alembic Mesh Sequence Cache so that all the animation gets exported to FBX?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Gilles

Comment: There's a tool for Maya that does this- https://github.com/aniketrajnish/Alembic-to-FBX-File-Maya/

Answer (score 3):

Humm. If we take into account that alembic is a cache format, similar to a dmm or pc2, what should be done is to export the first frame as .obj, and then create a dmm / pc2 of that sequence. I do not know if it works well ... The fact is that alembic separates the different meshes, so you must make a "key shape" for each component, not as a cache. This you can see if in the timeline, each frame is marked, which does not happen with alembic. That's where things go ... (I'm not very expert in Blender, but that will generate a considerable size in Mb ..) Besides, each software company has "its peculiarities" when it comes to interpreting a FBX.

Comment: By the way, I export from Maya to Blender a alembic in Ogawa format, and it looks painful of geometry ... I do not understand that! LOL

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do this, at least not for the generic case you describe. A mesh in Alembic can potentially be completely different from frame to frame, including a different topology. I don't think FBX even supports this.